# Is there a library for solving gaussian mixture models in pure scala program?

Tags: scala, probability, mixture-model

I want to solve GMM problem in my **pure scala program**. But I found many entries were all about Apache Spark. In some libraries like [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/) and [Smile](https://haifengl.github.io/api/scala/smile/), or even Github, I couldn't find something that met this requirement.

If you know any libraries that can solve GMM in pure scala program, please remind me. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't want to use spark and you can't find any other Scala solution, you can try to look for some java lib that does what you need.

Comment: @michaJlS Thanks. In this case, I should really consider using Java instead

Comment: Interesting question, although recommendations for software are off topic here; I think there might be a dedicated stackexchange for that, or maybe some other forum.